# String file parsing

Tags: c, parsing, input

```
char data1;
char* data2 = (char *)malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
char line[128];

while(fgets(line,sizeof line,filePtr) != NULL){
    sscanf(line, "%c = %[^\n]s\n", &data1, data2);
}
```

Inputfile:

```
f = g - 42;         
             //This is a new line
```

This code is meant to parse each line from the input file into 2 strings. Data1 should be f and data2 should be the rest of the string AFTER = .  But currently, the code does not properly initalize data2.

Tried printing data2 and there was no output

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd format string is incorrect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 127
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int main(void) {
    char data1;
    char data2[LEN+1];
    if(sscanf("f = g - 42;", "%c = %" str(LEN) "[^\n]", &data1, data2) != 2) {
        printf("sscanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("data1 = %c, data2 = %s\n", data1, data2);
}
```

and the output is:

```
data1 = f, data2 = g - 42;
```

Comment: Please update your question to be more precise than "did not work", "does not properly initalize" etc.   Your code operates on strings but you talk about a file.  It's easier to reason about a string.  Maybe you need to provide `od -a` of the relevant section of your file.  Or even better update your code with the exact data you want to parse (use my answer as a template instead of a snippet which limits what we can do to help you).  With respect to my answer,  need to know what is wrong with my answer.  Are you not getting the same output?  Do you need different input with different output?